# How to use function in function with simple chain list is C

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

my exercise is to read 2 simple chained lists from 2 files:

F1:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

F2:

```
6 7 8 9 10
```

Then list the common values and also list the union of the 2 structures. This is the code until now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
 int key;
 struct node *next;

} NodeT, NodeT2, NodeTcom, NodeTuni;

NodeT *search(NodeT *head, int givenKey)
{
 //TODO: search the given key and return the first node containing it or NULL
 while (head != NULL)
 {
     if (head -> key == givenKey)
     {
         return head;
     }
     else
     {
         head = head->next;
     }
 }
 return NULL;
}

void print_list(NodeT *head)
{
 //TODO: print list keys
 if (head == NULL)
     printf("Empty list!");
 else
     while (head != NULL)
     {
         printf("%d ", head->key);
         head = head->next;
     }

 printf("\n");
}

void insert_last(NodeT **head, NodeT **tail, int givenKey)
{
 //TODO: insert the given key in the last position of the list given by head and tail;
 NodeT * p = (NodeT*)malloc(sizeof(NodeT));
 p->key = givenKey;
 p->next = NULL;
 if (*tail == NULL)
 {
     *head = *tail = p;
 }
 else
 {
     (*tail)->next = p;
     *tail = p;
 }
}

void uniune(NodeTuni **headU, NodeTuni **tailU, NodeT *head){

     while (head != NULL)
 {

     //printf("%d", head->key);
     insert_last(**headU, **tailU, head->key);

     head = head->next;
 }
}

int main()
{
 ///PRIMA LISTA
 NodeT *first = NULL;
 NodeT *last  = NULL;

 FILE *fp;

 fp = fopen("E:\\F1.txt", "r");
 int temporary;
 while( fscanf(fp, "%d", &temporary) > 0)
 {
     insert_last(&first, &last, temporary);

 }
 fclose(fp);
 printf("Prima lista:");
 print_list(first);

 ///A DOUA LISTA
 NodeT2 *first2 = NULL;
 NodeT2 *last2  = NULL;

 FILE *fp2;
 fp2 = fopen("E:\\F2.txt", "r");
 while( fscanf(fp2, "%d", &temporary) > 0)
 {
     insert_last(&first2, &last2, temporary);

 }
 fclose(fp2);
 printf("A doua lista:");
 print_list(first2);

 //PARTEA DE VERIFICARE DUBLU:
 ///LISTA UNITA
 NodeTuni *firstU = NULL;
 NodeTuni *lastU  = NULL;

 uniune(&firstU, &lastU, first);

 printf("Lista comuna:");
 print_list(firstU);




 return 0;
}
```

The uniune function is not working. My problem is that I don't know how to use correctly pointers. Any type of help is appreciated (possible with concrete code).

Comment: What exactly means "It's obviously not working."? Please [edit] your question and show the complete non-working code in one code block, the error message or output you get and the expected output. Please fix all compiler errors and warnings. If you don't know how to fix some errors, ask about those specific ones.

Comment: You need to [edit] and show a [mcve].

Comment: Of course it is not working, because `///UNION PART` is not code to create the union of the two lists. Do you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: I edited it so that you can see the uniune function which I would like to use but it's not working. I think that in the main the calling of the function also has mistakes, but I don't know what mistakes

Comment: You can write an insertion routine that treats a linked list as a set: Insert in ascending order and don't insert if the key is already in the list. If you do that, finding the union is a metter of creating a new list and inserting all items of A and B into it in set-like fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You do not have to `typedef` multiple types. It is meaningless and
  just confusing.
- You do not have to use `tail` as long as you always append a new node
  to the last position of the list.
- It will be better to choose `*node`, not `**node` as the type
  of the arguments to the `insert_last()`. It is related to the
  return value of `insert_last()` mentioned below.
- Instead `insert_last()` should return the pointer to the created list.
  Then you can make the recursion easy.

Then would you please try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILE1 "E:\\F1.txt"
#define FILE2 "E:\\F2.txt"

typedef struct node {
    int key;
    struct node *next;

} node;

node *search(node *head, int givenKey)
{
    //TODO: search the given key and return the first node containing it or NULL
    while (head != NULL) {
        if (head->key == givenKey) {
            return head;
        } else {
            head = head->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

void print_list(node *head)
{
    //TODO: print list keys
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list!\n");
        return;
    }

    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", head->key);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

node *insert_last(node *head, int givenKey)
{
    //TODO: insert the given key in the last position of the list given by head
    // return the first node

    if (head == NULL) {
        node *p = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (p == NULL) return head;
        p->key = givenKey;
        p->next = NULL;
        return p;
    } else {
        head->next = insert_last(head->next, givenKey);
        return head;
    }
}

node *common(node *head1, node *head2)
{
    // create a new list of common values of head1 and head2
    // return the first node

    if (head1 == NULL || head2 == NULL) {
        printf("Empty list!\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    node *p = NULL;                             // create a new list
    while (head1 != NULL) {
        if (search(head2, head1->key)) {        // if found in both lists
            p = insert_last(p, head1->key);     // then append to the new list
        }
        head1 = head1->next;
    }
    return p;
}

node *uniune(node *head1, node *head2)
{
    // create a new list of union values of head1 and head2
    // return the first node

    node *p = NULL;                             // create a new list

    while (head1 != NULL) {
        if (! search(p, head1->key)) {          // copy new values of head1
            p = insert_last(p, head1->key);
        }
        head1 = head1->next;
    }

    while (head2 != NULL) {
        if (! search(p, head2->key)) {          // copy new values of head2
            p = insert_last(p, head2->key);
        }
        head2 = head2->next;
    }

    return p;
}

void free_list(node *head)
{
    // free the nodes of the list recursively
    if (head == NULL) return;
    free_list(head->next);
    free(head);
}

int main()
{
    ///PRIMA LISTA
    node *first1 = NULL;
    FILE *fp1 = fopen(FILE1, "r");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", FILE1);
        exit(1);
    }
    int temporary;
    while (fscanf(fp1, "%d", &temporary) > 0) {
        first1 = insert_last(first1, temporary);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    printf("Prima lista: ");
    print_list(first1);

    ///A DOUA LISTA
    node *first2 = NULL;
    FILE *fp2 = fopen(FILE2, "r");
    if (fp2 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s\n", FILE2);
        exit(1);
    }
    while (fscanf(fp2, "%d", &temporary) > 0) {
        first2 = insert_last(first2, temporary);
    }
    fclose(fp2);
    printf("A doua lista: ");
    print_list(first2);

    node *first3 = NULL;
    first3 = common(first1, first2);
    printf("Lista comuna: ");
    print_list(first3);

    node *first4 = NULL;
    first4 = uniune(first1, first2);
    printf("Lista unita: ");
    print_list(first4);

    free_list(first1);
    free_list(first2);
    free_list(first3);
    free_list(first4);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Prima lista: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
A doua lista: 6 7 8 9 10 
Lista comuna: 6 7 8 
Lista unita: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly. Can you explain that in the insert_last function why is this line necessary and what does it do:
        if (p == NULL) return head;

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it works. The line checks if the `malloc()` succeeded. We may better to display some message if `malloc()` failed due to `out of memory`.